# Is there a easiest way to make number of labels equal with pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dataset

when we use dataset with pandas.dataframe(), sometimes labels categories are not same ratio.

example) bike: car = 7:3

| price | label |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | bike |
| 100 | bike |
| 700 | bike |
| 300 | bike |
| 5500 | car |
| 400 | bike |
| 5200 | car |
| 310 | bike |
| 2000 | car |
| 20 | bike |

In this case, car and bike are not same ratio.
so, I want to make each category to be in same ratios.

car shows only 3 times, so 4 bike rows are deleted like this...

| price | label |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | bike |
| 300 | bike |
| 5500 | car |
| 5200 | car |
| 2000 | car |
| 20 | bike |

order is not important. I just want to get same ratio categories.

I did count car labels and bike labels, and check fewer labels(In this time, car is fewer labels), and read each rows to move another dataframe. It takes a lot of time, so
Inconvenience.

Is there a easiest way to make number of labels equal with pandas dataframe? or just count each label and make another dataframe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, take the minimum of each [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`GroupBy.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) :

```
out = df.groupby("label").head(min(df["label"].value_counts())) #or GroupBy.sample
```

Alternatively and in a @*mozway*, use a grouper :

```
g = df.groupby("label")

out = g.head(g["price"].size().min())
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   price label
0    200  bike
1    100  bike
2    700  bike
4   5500   car
6   5200   car
8   2000   car
```

[image]

Comment: Variant that reuses the `groupby`: `g = df.groupby('label') ; g.head(g['price'].size().min())`, it might be more efficient ;)

Comment: It's actually not more efficient, roughly the [same speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo0K8.png) ;)